# CSV file manipulation

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have two csv files ,let's say A and B . I realized that I have accidentally mixed up things and now in order to undo the mistake I want to write a shell script such that the data in third column of file A to be written in the fourth column of file B and data in fourth column of file B to be written in third column of file A. 
I know that "cut" command can be used to fetch data from specific columns but I don't know what command to use so as to write on a csv file after a particular number of occurrences of the delimiter on a single row.

How to write such a script?

Comment: it would be better if you provide us some sample input file and expected output.

Comment: @Rahul : let's say file A is supposed to be of format : [ field1, field2 ,field3 ,field 4] and file B : [ fieldX,fieldY,fieldZ,fieldV] and accidentally file A has become [field1,field2,fieldV,field4] and file B has become [fieldX,fieldY,fieldZ,field3].

Comment: You're probably looking for the `paste` command, plus shell process substitution to assemble the cut pieces - something like `paste -d, <(cut ... ) <(cut ... ) <(cut ...)`

Comment: @Theophrastus : It's not a homework assignment ...old enough to go to school :P

Comment: @steeldriver : What does this line paste -d , <(cut...) ... do ?

Comment: @privateryan: This question by nature requires that you put a sample input  and output for us to be more clear. Anyways I have a solution that might help. Please do gimme a f/b.

Comment: @Theophrastus : Yeah , I assure you of that. Wanted to learn how to do it using shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
A.csv:
1,2,V,4

B.csv:
X,Y,Z,3
```

Then

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1,2 A.csv) <(cut -d, -f4 B.csv) <(cut -d, -f4 A.csv)
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Replace `cut -d, -f` by `csvcut -c` and `paste -d,` by `csvjoin`, both from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), and you actually have an answer that work with CSV files. :)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is your friend

Make a copy of `fileA` to say `fileA.bak` & `fileB` to say `fileB.bak` :

```
#first changing fileB
awk -v FS="," 'NR==FNR{fileA[i++]=$3;next}{$4=fileA[j++];print}' fileA.bak fileB.bak > fileB 
#fileB should be Okay now.
#now changing fileA
awk -v FS="," 'NR==FNR{fileB[i++]=$4;next}{$3=fileA[j++];print}' fileB.bak fileA.bak > fileA
#fileA should be Okay now.
#verify that you have the desired contents in both fileA & fileB
#Now delete the backup files
rm fileA.bak fileB.bak
```

---

<sup>**Notes**

1. It is possible to combine both the `awk` scripts but why dividing them makes things clearer and more readable.

2. This solution assumes that you've same number of records in `fileA` and `fileB` as understood from the question.</sup>

Comment: If the fields contain quoted commas, awk isn't your friend anymore.

Comment: @ThomasDickey : You're right, but I hope that'd be a corner case :) . This was more a blind shot as the op didn't put any sample input.

Comment: @sjsam : I am yet to learn awk ..could you write something simpler ,like,cut command .if in case it is possible.

Comment: @privateryan : I think the other answer gave you a `cut` N `paste` solution already. This one is also similar to that provided you know a bit about `awk`

Comment: @ThomasDickey You can still mend your friendship with `awk` with the help of this tiny program: [`csvquote`](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote).  Very useful little helper.